# Form Object created in One class and getting its reference/reference in another class

Tags: java, swing

Please help me. I have in trouble in the following code. It is a bit confusing for me but easy for you. I hope you will find solution for this.

```
  class AddressBookInterface {
       JTextField txt = new JTextField();
  }
  class AddressBook {
      AddressBookInterface obj;
      String input = obj.txt.getName();     //this code, generate an error..........

    }
```

In class "AddressBookInterface", i have created a textfield. and in "AddressBook" class I want to get some input from user, which user enter in the textfield created in "AddressBookInterface" class.

Comment: what is the error.. 1) getName() returns the name of the component 2) your class Interface is a class and not an interface is confusing 3) to get some input from user you have to use some eventListener, then with `getText()` you get the input.

Comment: where is your main method. add a main method in your AddressBook class and get the text or name whatever you want inside this.

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is null, you need to initialize it. Otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`

```
class AddressBook {
    AddressBookInterface obj = new AddressBookInterface();
    String input = obj.txt.getName();    
}
```

**Sidenote:**

IMO, you should do the initialization in the instance block, something like this

```
class AddressBook {
    AddressBookInterface obj;
    String input;    

    {
        obj = new AddressBookInterface();
        input = obj.txt.getName();    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems is simple. AddressBookInterface obj is not instanced, it means, there is nothing inside obj, ask an empty object to give you the value of name and of course the error is occured. In this case, tried following code.

```
public class AddressBookInterface{
    JTextField txt;
    public AddressBookInterface(){
        // constructor
        // do something initial task here
        txt = new JTextField();
    }

    // Create this method so that you can reference from other class
    public String getName(){
        return txt.getText();
    }       
}
```

In your main class that contains model and controller. Initial the interface class and you can get the value by following.

```
// initial the interface
    AddressBookInterface interfaceObj = new AddressBookInterface();

    // get the value 
    String name = interfaceObj.getName();
```

I don't have experienced with designing MVC model. I hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner in Java. I want to code an Address Book with MVC model. In which I create a class for Interface only, one class for this Implementation (bussiness Logic layer), which implements the listeners. I know it may be dumb idea. bcoz i don't have full command on MVC.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it help you and don't forget to check the answer that you think it is best to your question. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

To get user input you have to use `getText()` rather than `getName()`.And to get the user input you can take approach from the observer pattern.

in `AddressBook` create an observer to listen changes from textfield in  `AddressBookInterface`.

Then your code would look like this.

```
class AddressBookInterface {
       JTextField txt = new JTextField();

     public void registerListener(String name, PropertyCHangeListener listener){
             txt.addPropertyChangeListener(name,listener);
     }       

 }

  class AddressBook {
      String input;
      private PropertyChangeListener listener = new MyPropertyChangeListener();


      public PropertyChangeListener getListener(){
            return listener;
      }

      private class MyPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener{
             @Override
             public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt){
                        if(evt == null)
                             return;

                     if(evt.getPropertyName().equals("text")){
                         input = (String) evt.getNewValue();
                     }
             }

       }

}
```

And in someplace where you create the objects.

```
   AddresBookInterface addres = new AddresBookInterface();
   AddresBook book = new AddresBook();
   addres.registerListener("text",book.getListener());
```